# TeamCity Twitter Notifier?

Tags: build, twitter, teamcity, continuous-integration

Has anyone built something to send out your TeamCity build status with Twitter?  Can this be done with TeamCity's Jabber support?

Comment: I'll post a plugin in the next few hours

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I saw this post and thought I'd write you a plugin.

[here's the blog post on how to do it](http://sleepoverrated.com/archive/2009/03/twitter-notifications-with-teamcity/)

and here's the google code project

[teamcity-twitter-notifier](http://code.google.com/p/teamcity-twitter-notifier/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [sleepoverrated.com](https://sleepoverrated.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/ttn-05.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It's working now with hardcoded username/pass so a little cleanup and documentation, it'll be ready tomorrow

Comment: I added support for custom messages in the latest release

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for the same thing. I haven't succeeded in finding any Jabber-to-Twitter gateways yet. A native Twitter Notifier would be really neat though :-)